# ModelState is invalid when post a form date in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am stuck with the datatime input when post a form. The `datetime` didn't match with model so the `ModelState` is invalid. I already did research about this problem but couldn't find any solution. Could someone please help me solve this problem?

This is my code - `Student` model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the view:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
@model Student
<div class="text-center">
    <form method="post" asp-action="Index">
        @if (TempData["Error"]!= null)
        {
            <span>@TempData["Error"]</span>
        }
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="14/01/2024 01:04 PM" asp-for="StartDate" asp-format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(Student std) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        TempData["Error"] = std.StartDate.ToString() + " is OK" ;
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["Error"] = ModelState.Values.First().Errors.First().ErrorMessage;
    }

    return View();
}
```

This is the result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hptcO.png]

This is my demo code: https://github.com/bondaigames/WebApplication1

Answer (score 0):

We set `DateTime` StartDate, but the value is  `string` "14/01/2024 01:04 PM", so model bind cannot bind the "14/01/2024 01:04 PM" to StartDate.This is because the parsed DateTime is not valid in the en-US culture as 14 is not considered a valid month.But we can get string "14/01/2024 01:04 PM" by Request.Form["StartDate"].

Then we can use [ParseExact()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-8.0) to parse `String` to `DateTime`, parse a string that is formatted exactly as specified by the format string argument and culture-specific format information, and it throws a FormatException if the string cannot be parsed into a DateTime value that matches the exact format string.

If the input string matches the exact format string, we can  remove the ModelState error.

Have a little change to your Index :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(Student std) 
{

    var dateString = Request.Form["StartDate"];
    IFormatProvider provider = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    string format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt";
    DateTime parsedDate;
    try
   {
        parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
        Console.WriteLine(parsedDate); /* Output: 1/14/2024 1:04:00 PM */
        ModelState.Remove("StartDate");
    }
    catch (FormatException ex)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
   
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       
        TempData["Error"] = dateString.ToString() + " is OK";
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["Error"] = ModelState.Values.First().Errors.First().ErrorMessage;
       
    }
    return View();
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
"but the value is string "14/01/2024 01:04 PM", so model bind cannot bind the "14/01/2024 01:04 PM" to StartDate" => It is not a string. It is actually already parsed to datetime. The problem is because of the culture on the server. My server is default to MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt so that's why it cannot parse the 14 to the month. I tried to set the culture and the format date at the time of running the server. And it works fine to me. :)

Comment: Hi @user2361451 " It is actually already parsed to datetime. " How it parsed to datetime?

Comment: Qing Guo: as on the input. I set type=datetime so It should not be a string. If you change 14 below to 12 so it is working well.

Comment: Hi@user2361451 , ok, that's fine. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Hi @user2361451 ",I set type=datetime so It should not be a string."   It's  a date and time format string , then the parsed DateTime is not valid in the en-US culture as 14 is not considered a valid month as you said.